# Start-Job | Wait-Job returns immediately does not run code

Tags: powershell

I am trying to wait on a long process using the docs for [Start-Job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job?view=powershell-5.1) and [Wait-Job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/wait-job?view=powershell-5.1):

```
$7zip = "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"

# This works fine, takes minutes
# & $7zip a -mx=5 output.7z .\largefile.txt

# These return immediately as complete with no errors
# Start-Job -ScriptBlock {& $7zip a -mx=5 output.7z .\largefile.txt } | Wait-Job
Start-Job -Name myjob -ScriptBlock {7z.exe a -mx=5 output1.7z .\largefile.txt } | Wait-Job
```

As above, not only does Wait-Job not wait, but the command in the ScriptBlock is not run (no file output). I *have* to get this to work in PowerShell 5.1 so I think my options are limited. What am I missing? No errors visible anywhere that I can see, the commands just complete right away.

Edit: The leftover `-Name myjob` arg above is because I also tried it with `Wait-Job -Name myjob`. No different.

Comment: Seems like you just need to change `& $7zip` to `& $using:7zip`.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I just tried that, no change. Returns immediately, does not run the 7zip command. I use the `&` in the line above (without Start-Job) and it works fine.

Comment: mmm your code works fine for me changing `& $using:7zip`. The other possible issue I see is a relative path in `.\largefile.txt`, try using the absolute path of that file. Then it should work fine

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon is right: *the default working directory for jobs is hardcoded. The Windows default is `$HOME\Documents` and on Linux or macOS the default is `$HOME`. The script code running in the background job needs to manage the working directory as needed.*

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Yes! It was the relative paths screwing things up. Works fine, now. Thanks for the whack with the clue-by-four. I'll mark it as an answer if you want to re-write it.

Comment: @JosefZ Huh, did not know that. And yes, there are the empty output files under Documents. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 issues with your code:

- `$7Zip` doesn't exist in the Job's scope, you need to use the [`$using:` scope modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-7.4#the-using-scope-modifier) to pass the value of that variable to this scope.
- You should never use relative paths as arguments of your external command, try to use absolute path, in this case you can use `Convert-Path` to get the absolute path of your file if needed. Then again, you can pass it in to the job scope with `$using:`. As stated in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job?view=powershell-5.1#description) and noted by [JosefZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3439404/josefz):

  > The default working directory for jobs is hardcoded. The Windows default is `$HOME\Documents` and on Linux or macOS the default is `$HOME`. The script code running in the background job needs to manage the working directory as needed.

  As another alternative, you can use a relative path but you must also use [`-WorkingDirectory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job?view=powershell-7.4#-workingdirectory), do note, this parameter was added in PowerShell 7 and is not available in Windows PowerShell 5.1.

```
$7zip = 'C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe'
$path = Convert-Path .\largefile.txt -ErrorAction Stop

if (Test-Path $7zip) {
    Start-Job -ScriptBlock { & $using:7zip a -mx=5 output.7z $using:path } |
        Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob
}
```

As aside, the reason why you're not seeing any errors is because you're never receiving the job's output with `Receive-Job` (why I'm changing `Wait-Job` for it).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! Indeed, I was reading through `Receive-Job` when this answer beeped through. In my original research I had the internal command itself writing to a log but left that all out to make the question clearer. `Receive-Job` is much cleaner, though 